# Polar plot in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, polar-coordinates

I have a problem. Im trying to do a polar plot, the fact it's that i want to plot some theorical line as some experimental data in the plot. But the theorical line has a range different of the experimental data because i had to do it like that to had gnuplot paint it.

I have the following script:

```
####
reset
set encoding utf8
set size 1,1
set terminal epslatex
set output "direccionalidad.tex"

unset border

set polar 
set angles degrees #set gnuplot on degrees instead of radians

set style line 10 lt 1 lc 0 lw 0.3
set grid polar 30 #set the grid to be displayed every 60 degrees
set grid ls 10

set trange[-90:90]

f(t)=27.934*sin(1.81651*t+96.1991) # Theorical line

set xrange[-31:32]
set yrange[-30:30]

set xtics axis #disply the xtics on the axis instead of on the border
set ytics axis


set xtics scale 0 #"remove" the tics so that only the y tics are displayedj

set ytics (0, 6, 12) #make the ytics go from the center (0) to 6000 with incrment of 1000

unset ytics
set xtics ("5" 6, "15" 16.5, "30" 32) 
# set the xtics only go from 0 to 6000 with increment of1000 but do not display anything. This has to be done otherwise the grid will not be displayed correctly.

set rtics (5,15,30)
set rtics format ' ' scale 0


set_label(x, text) = sprintf("set label '%s' at (32*cos(%f)), (32*sin(%f))     center", text, x, x) #this places a label on the outside

eval set_label(0, "0") 

eval set_label(30, "30")

eval set_label(60, "60")

eval set_label(90, "90")

eval set_label(120, "120")

eval set_label(150, "150")

eval set_label(180, "180")

eval set_label(-150, "-150")

eval set_label(-120, "-120")

eval set_label(-90, "-90")

eval set_label(-60, "-60")

eval set_label(-30, "-30")

set size square

#PLOTS
plot "direccionalidaddatos.txt" u 1:3 pointtype 7 ps 2 lt 1 lw 3 lc rgb 'blue' notitle ,\
f(t) dt '-' lc rgb 'blue' notitle 

#ACABAMOS

###
```

And here there are some examples of columns in the direccionalidaddatos.txt archive, the column in the middle it's just the angle in radians but it's usless cause i just want the angle in degrees so just ignore it ;):

-90 -1.570796327    0.1

-85 -1.483529864    0.2

-80 -1.396263402    0.4

-75 -1.308996939    0.7

-70 -1.221730476    1.1

-65 -1.134464014    1.7

-60 -1.047197551    2.5

### #

And the result it is the image [Polar plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3s7T.png)

As you see in the image there are two branches that have no points, i want those branches to simply don't disappear cause they don't mean notihng in the graphic.So if anyone knows a form to made dissapear the branches, or to improve the script let me know hehe.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you just reduce the sampled range for the second plot component?

```
plot "direccionalidaddatos.txt" u 1:3 pointtype 7 ps 2 lt 1 lw 3 lc rgb 'blue' notitle ,\
     [-52:45] '+' using 1:(f($1)) with lines dt '-' lc rgb 'blue' notitle
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it works perfect,but it plots the point with a cross, you know how to do it for only plot it with dashed lines only